# Does Cached includes Mapped pages in /proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

The Linux kernel definition for Cached memory does not mention it includes Shmem and Mapped pages (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), but I've found some references where it is stated they are included (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353283/what-does-the-linux-proc-meminfo-mapped-topic-mean, https://241931348f64b1d1.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/linux-memory-explaned-procmeminfo/).

Is it legitimate/does it make sense to compute cached pages as:
`Cached_Pages = Cached - Shmem - Mapped` ?

Thank you!